# How much does it cost to use a contract?

Tags: transactions, gas, contract-invocation, gas-price

Still new to ethereum and would like to know the price for a contract.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The total cost of a transaction that creates a contract or executes a contract is based on 2 factors:

`gasUsed` is the total gas that is consumed

`gasPrice` specified in the transaction

**`Total cost = gasUsed * gasPrice`**

#### gasUsed

Each operation in the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) was [assigned a number of how much gas it consumes.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/52/42)  `gasUsed` is summing up all the gas for all the operations executed.  There is a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit) which offers a glimpse to some of the analysis behind them.

For [estimating](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/197/42) `gasUsed`, there is an [estimateGas API with some caveats](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/266/42).

#### gasPrice

A user constructs and signs a transaction, and each user may specify whatever `gasPrice` they desire, this includes zero.  However, the Ethereum clients launched at Frontier had a default gasPrice of 0.05e12 wei.  As miners optimize for their revenue, if most transactions are being submitted with a gasPrice of 0.05e12 wei, it would be difficult to convince a miner to accept a transaction that specified a lower, or zero, gasPrice.  How the default was chosen is asked in this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/324/42).

#### Example

Let's take a contract that just adds 2 numbers.  From the spreadsheet above `ADD` consumes 3 gas.

The approximate cost, using the default gas price, would be:

3 * 0.05e12 = 1.5e11 wei

Since 1 Ether is 1e18 wei, the total cost would be 0.00000015 Ether.

This is a simplification since it ignores some costs, such as the cost of passing the 2 numbers to contract, before they can even be added.