# How do I figure out how much USD it will cost to deploy or execute methods on a contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, gas, evm, gas-estimate

Is there a simple tool for this or do I have to calculate it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How much does it cost to use a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-much-does-it-cost-to-use-a-contract)

`Total ETH cost = gasUsed * gasPrice`

Multiply the result by the USD price per ETH.

browser-solidity can help provide the `gasUsed`, and you have control over the `gasPrice`.  The USD price fluctuates, and it's not much multiplication so there might not yet be a tool that multiplies all 3 values.

Comment: It may not always be so easy to test everything in browser solidity - another option is to run on testnet with excessive amounts of Gas and use estnet.etherscan.io to find out how much you actually used...