# Can a transaction's gas cost change?

Tags: gas, out-of-gas

I encountered a strange issue on Ropsten Testnet. I deployed a payable contract successfully and tried to send ethers to it. I didn't know how much gas it required, so I gradually increased `gasLimit`. After a few "out of gas" errors, I finally made a successful call.

I inspected the successful transaction on etherscan.io and noted down the `Gas Used By Transaction` field, let's say it was 30,123. Then I tried to send the exact same transaction (with 31,000 gas to be safe), and I was very surprised that this new call also failed with "out of gas", i.e. it consumed all of the 31,000 gas..

-How- can the same transaction require different amounts of gas? Is it up to the miner? It shouldn't be.

If relevant, my transaction does not change anything inside the contract. The contract just takes the money and sends it back to the sender, i.e. `contract myContract{ function () payable { msg.sender.send(msg.value); } }` But -I think- even if it did change something, the gas cost should remain constant. It should only depend on the contract code, and not the state, right?

Thanks for any help,

### Update

I kept trying (and failing), until I increased `gasLimit` like crazy, up to 50,000 and it worked again! with the exact same 30,123 gas used. This makes sense, but it's still curious why it didn't work before, with more than enough amounts of gas.

### Update 2

I created the contract with this source code:

```
contract c{ function () payable { msg.sender.send(msg.value); } }
```

I compiled it with Solidity and deployed [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x3fc6fa6e08b83576912e909f9835e824204ae8f1), and tried to send 1 wei (which it will send back to [me](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xaa546ba3b8ad91965c62bb3485b9ef933bd1d125)), here are my trials:

1. With 50,000 gas, success! It used 28,520 of it. You can see it [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x87222e789a91eb735d51a438e579c526218c422286b699c119c1429d7c7adedb).
2. With 28,521 gas, fail.. It's [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x7109aa9362049b9cd91d2b48db49914599fb6e2854e91cb882fc563dd02549d5)
3. It also failed with 30,000 gas, [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x8d97ae9ad01c8f2c59e66e009fc68ea4c273d4caf0d549037065748c4a07e2d4).

Feel free to send your test ethers to it, if you want to try. Don't worry, it won't keep them :)

Comment: After it worked with 50K gas, did it start working again with 31K gas?  Does it fail with 49,999 gas?  Please let us know when you figure it out and possibly post your own answer.

Comment: @eth I still have cases where it fails with -more than- enough gas, still not sure what the issue is. I updated the question with examples.

Comment: When you say it "fails", what exactly does this mean? Does it actually get mined and throw an exception exception​? Is all of the gas used up?

Comment: @TjadenHess Yes, it fails with "out of gas", you can see in the last 2 examples in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a transaction's gas cost change?

Yes.

> Is it up to the miner? It shouldn't be.

By incorporating your transaction into a block, the miners are providing a service, which means you're taking part in a market.

The explanation of `gasPrice` in [this previous answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2760/52) helps illustrate this. (In short, miners will optimise the `gasPrice` for their revenue.)

This further previous question might also be useful in explaining why gas estimates can be inaccurate, though it's perhaps less useful if you're certain nothing is changing in your contract: [What are the limitations to estimateGas and when would its estimate be considerably wrong?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera)

Comment: Thanks! The second link was very informative in not trusting gas estimations, and I understand why `gasPrice` can change among miners. However, I'm still confused why `gasUsed` changes for the same operation. Are you sure it's about my contract? Anyways, maybe I will create a separate question for this, with more transparent examples. Thanks for your help.