# Why this function doesnt need Gas for execution?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapp-development, view

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract Lottery{

    address public manager; 
    address[] public players;

    function Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;

    }


    function enter() public payable{
        require (msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }


    function random() public view returns (uint){
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, players));
    }

}
```

I executed random function after being deployed on Rinkeby testnet, but no ether has been deducted as GasFee. Please correct me if i am wrong, but random functions is calculating a Psudorandom function and it involves computations. Shoudnt it require gas to execute?

One guess: Any view function which doesnt change state doesnt need Gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

Clients have the option, but most clients will call the function in a read-only fashion, seeing that there is nothing for the network to verify because it doesn't change the state.

More details: [When to use "View" and "Pure" in place of "Constant"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28898/when-to-use-view-and-pure-in-place-of-constant/28900#28900)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Now, I get it. Since it doesnt change state..it doesnt needs to be replicated to other machines which means no verification needed. Even if i would like to make 1000s request to this function in a second, they can only be made to my copy of Blockchain on my server or machine. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes, given that it's read-only, your own node can inspect the local copy of the chain (which it presumes is the same as everyone else's) and evaluate and respond. There are non-obvious subtleties, so I linked the other answer and the blog post. The blog post unpacks the issues people tend to get confused about.