# Function which only reads data still using gas/tx fee

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas

I have a function call  which only reads data from contract but it still costs gas to execute:

```
   function foo(int256 x) public returns (bool) {
    if(tuna[x].validOnce == true){
      if(dog[x] == true)
        return true;
      else
         return false;
    }

    else
      return true;

 }
```

I ve read about pure and view that I can add to my method header. However Im not sure if this is a case in point where I need to use such headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
function foo(int256 x) public view returns (bool) {
  if(tuna[x].validOnce == true){
    if(dog[x] == true)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  } else return true;
}
```

This will return the value instead of a transaction hash. Gas accounnting will still unfold but gas will be returned unless this is called from another contract that is not doing a read-only operation.

Incidentally, you use `view` instead of `pure` because this function reads data.

Have a look here, as well: [When to use "View" and "Pure" in place of "Constant"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28898/when-to-use-view-and-pure-in-place-of-constant)

Hope it helps.