# Solidity Invalid implicit conversion from string memory to bytes memory requested

Tags: solidity, error, string, bytes, data-types

```
pragma solidity ^0.5

contract ProofOfExistence {

    // ... some code here

    function proofFor(string memory document) public view returns(bytes32) {
        return sha256(document);
    }

    // ... some more code here
}
```

Gives following error :

> TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
>   implicit conversion from string memory to bytes memory requested.

I am unable to understand why this error is coming.

**UPDATE :**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;
// Proof of Existence contract, version 3
contract ProofOfExistence3 {
  mapping (bytes32 => bool) private proofs;
  // store a proof of existence in the contract state
  function storeProof(bytes32 proof)  public{
    proofs[proof] = true;
  }
  // calculate and store the proof for a document
  function notarize(string memory document) public {
   **bytes32 proof = proofFor(document);**
    storeProof(proof);
  }
  // helper function to get a document's sha256
  function proofFor(bytes memory document) public pure returns (bytes32)  {
    return sha256(document);
  }
  // check if a document has been notarized
  function checkDocument(string memory document) view public returns (bool) {
    **bytes32 proof = proofFor(document);**
    return hasProof(proof);
  }
  // returns true if proof is stored
  function hasProof(bytes32 proof) view public returns(bool) {
    return proofs[proof];
```

**UPDATE ERROR** After the update as suggested I am getting the same error but on the lines having ** ...** this time. Why is it coming now?
Thanks

Comment: It's better if you can copy-paste your code, rather than attaching a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument to `sha256` should be in `bytes`. But you're passing `document` which is a `string`. Following would work.

```
function proofFor(bytes memory document) public pure returns(bytes32) {
    return sha256(document);
}
```

And a side note - your function doesn't need to be `view` type since it is not viewing any storage items. This can be made a `pure` function which has neither side effects nor storage viewing. More details can be found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28903/16301).

**UPDATE :**

If changing `string` to `bytes` gives errors at other function calls you can either convert them to `bytes` as well or else you can cast `string` to `bytes` as @Mikhail suggested. Then that would be;

```
function proofFor(string memory document) public pure returns(bytes32) {
    return sha256(bytes (document));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! after changing the code as u suggested I am getting errors in the other part.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.5;
// Proof of Existence contract, version 3
contract ProofOfExistence3 {
  mapping (bytes32 => bool) private proofs;
  // store a proof of existence in the contract state
  function storeProof(bytes32 proof)  public{
    proofs[proof] = true;
  }
  // calculate and store the proof for a document
  function notarize(string memory document) public {
   bytes32 proof = proofFor(document);
    storeProof(proof);
  }

Comment: I have added the code but seems quite ugly here!

Comment: now the error has shifted to this line  ... bytes32 proof = proofFor(document);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance...Now the problem is solved!

Comment: Yeah done now !

Answer (score 4):

Should probably be

```
return sha256(bytes (document));
```