# what is the lowest gas price that clients (Geth / Parity) relay

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, gas-price, clients

I read [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1669/16) that nodes (at least Geth) only relay transactions that have a gas price above some limit. What is that default limit currently?

As also mentioned there it is probably not zero as that would be a huge DDoS risk. On the other hand I see some 0 gas price tx being mined. Does that mean those tx are being created by the miner themselves or are they being relayed by some nodes that manually lowered the limit?