# Should I use the default gas price?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, gas-price

I see that there is a default gas price, but does everyone use it? Do people get away with paying much less for gas? Are there any websites that track how long transactions take at different gas prices?

[Ethstats](https://ethstats.net/) shows gas price as 1/20th of the default. Does anyone know how accurate this is as a minimum?

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/can-i-set-the-gas-price-to-whatever-i-want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default gas price is 50 shannon on frontier, 20 on Homestead. 
(remember to [upgrade](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/48arax/homestead_release_faq/))

Vitalik recently [ran a test](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/499a7w/gas_prices_are_already_kinda_down_to_20_shannon/) to see how long it took for transactions with different gas prices to be included, finding:

> Hence, if you are fine with a ~2 minute extra confirmation time, you can start sending transactions with a 20 shannon gas price now,