# Gas price in ETH unit

Tags: transactions, ether, gas-price, fees

I am wondering if there's a website that provides the price of the standard gas limit (21000 Gas, transaction cost for sending ETH) in ETH unit.

I checked Ether.Fund site, but it provides the gas price in BTC and is based on ether pre-sale rate.

Answer (score 29):

There is no fixed gas price that transactions must have.

You can specify the gas price, and if you set a gas price within certain bounds, the transaction will be accepted by miners using their default values and [oracle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1133/42).

The default gas price is now 0.02 microether which is equivalent to:

- 0.00000002 Ether (.02 * 1e-6)
- 0.02e12 wei
- 20000000000 wei
- 20e9 wei
- **20 Gwei** (gigawei)
- 0.02 szabo

When you send ETH, your client (Geth or Parity) will use the default gas price of 0.02 microether.

If 1 ETH is $10, 1 gas will cost `0.00000002 * 10` dollars.

If ETH is $10, 21000 gas will cost `0.00000002 * 10 * 21000 = 0.0042` dollars, which is **0.42 cents**.

If ETH is $1000, 21000 gas will cost `0.00000002 * 1000 * 21000 = 0.42` dollars, which is **42 cents**.

Comment: Um, wouldn't it be .0042 cents, not .42 cents?

Comment: @Brain2000 0.5 dollars would be 50 cents, so is there a mistake elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see.  My bad.  The way it's written I was mistaking it for $0.42, not 0.42 of one single cent as you intended.

Comment: @eth Is the gas price for public and private network same? Because in my private network I can see gas price=0.02 ether per million gas but from this [link](http://ether.fund/tool/gas-price) gas price is 10 szabo= 0.00001 ETH. I don't know which price should I consider?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh: What you see in your network is correct; the link is old.

Comment: Same calculation with current ether price (250$)  is 0,105$ and probably get larger. Is there any miners having less than default gas price (0.02 microether)? And what would the probability for miners having very low gas price to deploy a transaction? @eth

Comment: @Avatar http://ethgasstation.info suggests that a gas price of 2 Gwei (0.002 microether) will be confirmed in less than 5 minutes on average.

Comment: Just corrected the dollars to cents conversion, I believe? @CaptainBli confirm?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed gas price that transactions must have.

However, you can use the [fast gas feed](https://feeds.chain.link/fast-gas-gwei) from the Chainlink decentralized oracle service to tell you what gas price you need to set for your transaction to go through "fast". The fast gas feed gets independent updates from different [oracles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85178/what-is-an-oracle) and posts an aggregate of it on-chain, so anyone can know what the current price of "speed" on the network is.

A transaction going through in under 2 minutes at the moment is considered to be fast.