# Is Ethereum suitable for a storage application?

Tags: blockchain, storage, database

I'm interested to make an app to store some data and I'd rather think that the blockchain might not be the only or the right solution for me. I'd like the users to contribute data and to make that data impossible to censor or take down. So if more people (or even everyone) has a copy of it, thats what I want.

But there is no contract, no mining, and its enough if the data is replicated a few times, not needed for each users to have the whole blockchain. But I see that the blockchain can act as a distributed database and I dont know other technologies like it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_(database)

Comment: Relevant: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block

Comment: Relevant (possible dupe?): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/how-can-i-store-data-in-ethereum-blockchain

Comment: If you're not requiring any smarts to your data, investigate IPFS.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/storing-document-file-in-blockchain/7848#7848

Answer (score 1):

### Storing on the Blockchain

#### IPFS:

Have you considered using IPFS? It is designed for the kind of use case you seem to be describing:

https://ipfs.io/

#### Swarm:

Ethereum also has its own storage system in the works, called Swarm.

http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/theswarm.eth/