# What would be the probability for miners having very low gas price to deploy a transaction?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, miner

Here is guide for the [Gas price in ETH unit Calculation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3939/4575):

> If 1 ETH is $10, 1 gas will cost 0.00000002 * 10 dollars.
>
> If ETH is $10, 21000 gas will cost 0.00000002 * 10 * 21000 = 0.0042
>   dollars, which is 0.42 cents.

Based on the calculation shown, with the current `ether` price (250$) the result will be 0,105 dollars instead of 0.42 cents, which is very expensive in my opinion.

**[Q]** Is there any miners having `gas price` less than the default gas price(0.02 microether)? If yes, what would be the probability for miners having very low gas price to deploy a transaction?