# The gas price on the Ropsten test net today rose from 0.211 ether per million gas to 1.8 ether per million gas, why?

Tags: gas, gas-price, ropsten

Seems like Ethereum adjusts its gas price to meet demand. How does it do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1113/87