# Gas price in Ethereum PoA

Tags: go-ethereum, poa

I have two questions about gas price in Ethereum PoA

1.What if I set the **gasPrice** as **0** while starting the geth node? will it cause any problem in future.

2.What if I set the **gasPrice** as **1** while starting the geth node, as **sealer nodes** will not get any reward but the sealer node will have to pay some ethers for a transaction, so after some time the account will be short of ethers, so how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1 ) If you set gas price to 0 transactions will not have any cost(ether cost), in PoA there is no reward for making a block, ether is either given from initialization or not given at all.

2 ) If you set gas price to 1 you will end up in short after some time ( long probably ) but since no reward is given, there will a problem. A way of overcoming that problem is to handover ether from a known address that you give  a certain amount of ether from the start ( genesis block ) to the newely created accounts. an other way is to not use gas ( set gas price to 0)

3 ) Check here : [Is gas burned in a PoA network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66034/is-gas-burned-in-a-poa-network/66094#66094) . This explains that in clique PoA protocol, the ether is always in circulation and it goes from user fees to block signers in a complete circle.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66034/is-gas-burned-in-a-poa-network/66094#66094

Comment: @ivicaa Yes it appears, it's quite untrue if we talked only about clique PoA. But in PoA in a private network (in general), collecting the Ether and handing it to the signers is not necessary unless the network grows significantly and the range of needs and incentive for each participant becomes wider.
The span idea is totally true.