# Is gas burned in a PoA network?

Tags: gas, poa

I read in [another thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47793/gas-price-in-ethereum-poa) that since sealer nodes don't get rewards, the gas spent in the network is burned and doesn't go to anyone.

However to limit spam, there needs to be a non-zero gas price. Do I need to find a sweet spot between gas price and spam? Is there a way to set a non-zero gas price while not burning it?

Alternatively, would I need to modify the code to achieve such a feature (like, sealers get the gas)?

Comment: Can you link the other thread you're talking about? AFAIK gas goes to sealer nodes as normal in the main Ethereum-based PoA systems.

Comment: I linked to that thread, which doesn't include any proof, but since it's the only information I found...

Comment: The question in that thread is very confused, I'd ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about geth Clique PoA, then ether used to pay gas costs is not burned, but collected by the sealer. So basically it circulates.

See https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225#issuecomment-428911386

> Ether doesn't vanish from the system. It just gets redistributed. Any fees paid by users are going fully to the signers, so they themselves can use that Ether to do whatever. It's a closed system.

Also in PoA, you should work with gasPrice > 0 in order to avoid spam.