# Manually setting transaction fee when transacting using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, fees

I am using geth to transfer some ether to another account.

After `geth attach` to my node, I just do is the following

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])

eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:'0x....', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")})
```

In a transaction I did a few days ago I paid 0.00168 Ether ($2.30) transaction fees. The transaction was confirmed in under a minute, so I want to to manually reduce the transaction fee if I am not in a rush to get my transaction confirmed.

In [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/can-i-set-the-gas-price-to-whatever-i-want) post I see that you can set the gas price to any value you want by supplying a `gasPrice` argument in `eth.sendTransaction()`. I also now check in [ethgasstation.info](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php) that a "standard" gas price is 114 Gwei. I also see in the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) that the units of `gasPrice` is wei.

My question is how would I put my desired gas price in my sending transaction? I don't want to make a big mistake with units and drain my whole account by paying huge fees! Would I put something like

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:'0x....', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gasPrice:114e9})
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what you wanna do is:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:'0x....', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gas: 21000, gasPrice: 50000000000});
```

In my example, `gas` is the gas amount used by the transaction *( it should always be 21000 when transfering ethers, because that's how much ether transfer costs on the ethereum blockchain )* and the `gasPrice` parameter defines how fast you want your transaction to be confirmed *( the higher tax you pay the faster your transaction will be accepted by the miners and confirmed )*. The value is in wei, you can [this eth calculator](https://eth-converter.com/) to convert gwei into wei and set the proper value. The value that I've set in the example 50000000000 wei are actually 50 gwei.

Comment: So is it mandatory to supply a `gas` argument when supplying a `gasPrice`?

Comment: Both parameters are optional.