# Solidity compiler doesn't work in the Javascript Console

Tags: json-rpc, solc

I'm using Geth 1.4.5-stable along with Solc version 0.3.5-0 both on Linux. It is run on a Digital Ocean server. I have a fully synced testnet chain and I'm trying to compile contracts from within the Javascript console.

**Steps I've taken**:

A. I added Solidity to PATH with `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/solc`

B. I connected to the console in an another shell window with the following command:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,admin" \
  --solc /usr/bin/solc attach ipc:/home/physes/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

This seems to work fine, and I can use other RPI API commands.

C. I was testing out a Greeter contract.

i)

```
var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
```

ii)

```
var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
```

At this point it fails, and I get:

```
solc: exit status 1
Unknown exception during compilation.
at web3.js:3119:20
at web3.js:6023:15
at web3.js:4995:36
at <anonymous>:1:23
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not directly /usr/bin/solc to PATH, but that should not cause your error

Comment: Ok, I don't think that's what caused it (also tried without the --solc flag). Possibly important context: this is being run on a Digital Ocean server. It works fine on my local Geth instance.

Comment: Are you using the same version in both (local and remote)? The  last version I worked with no problemes was geth 1.3.6. Probably you should report the issue in github.

Comment: I've just tested the new version of `solc` and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Solidity compiler.

Here is a quick test:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ echo '' | solc
Unknown exception during compilation.
```

See [`eth.compile.solidity` fails with solc version 0.3.5 #2703](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2703), which links to [Exception on compilation from stdin #651](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/651).

And the issue [Fix crash for input from stdin. #652](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/652) has been fixed, but will take an unknown (hopefully short) amount of time to make it into the repository packages.

This is the code change for the fix - [Fix crash for input from stdin. #652 - Files changed](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/652/files).

You can try installing the previous version of `solc`.

Or one workaround offered in the first link above:

> For anyone who wants a temporary workaround, you can clone this repo: https://github.com/mattdf/solidity-static and do a build in docker, then copy the solc file to your install. It makes a statically compiled build of solc so it should work on most distros.

### Update 10/07/2016

I have installed the latest version of `solc` and it is now working correctly:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.5-0/RelWithDebInfo-Linux/g++/Interpreter
```

And testing for the exception in the previous version:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ echo '' | solc
user@Kumquat:~$
```

Comment: Great answer. One similar issue- on my local machine with the older version of Solidity that works, a problem I'm having is that there is no feedback. I'm using `geth attach etc. etc.` with the blockchain in another window, and while it accepts the javascript input, there is no response and I get no `contract mined!` at the end. Is this an issue with attach?

Comment: Just confirming - is your account is unlocked using `--unlock 0`? See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6028/1268 .