# Gas cost of different computations

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price

Is there somewhere a list showing the different cost of different calculations?
For example:

- Perform transaction: 21'000 gas
- calculate a hash: 30 gas
- addition of two numbers: 3 gas
- cycle in a loop: 1 gas
- ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look to http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html.

Also, check the following spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit

Comment: You might also want to check out this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-were-gas-costs-chosen-for-the-ethereum-virtual-machine-instructions).