# Fixed amount of Gas required for ether transfer

Tags: solidity, web3js

why required gas for ether transfer fixed to  21000wei ?how they calculate the gas limit?could someone explain all computational steps involved during transfer ether from one account to another?

Comment: 21000 gas hasn't been explained but comes from the spreadsheet in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-were-gas-costs-chosen-for-the-ethereum-virtual-machine-instructions

Comment: as mentioned some are arbitrary and some are specifically defined mean in future it can be changed??

Comment: Rare but [possible](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-160.md).